# Filter data from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

**Table1:**

table1Id,

some fields....

**Table2:**

table2Id,

table1Id,

ValidTill (Datetime),

some fields...

there are two concepts, Active records and Inactive records.

**Inactive records** = records from `Table1` which are in `Table2` with `ValidTill` date less than today.

**Active records** = records from `Table1` which are in `Table2` with `ValidTill` date more than today. Doesn't matter if such multiple `table1Id` present in `Table2` whose `ValidTill < today's date`, if at least one record present in `Table2` whose `Validtill > today's date`, then it will be considered Active record and should not fall under Inactive record.

**Queries:**

Active :

```
Select * from Table1 where table1Id in (Select table1Id from Table2 where ValidTill > GETDATE())
```

InActive :

```
Select * from Table1 where table1Id in (Select table1Id from Table2 where ValidTill < GETDATE())
```

with these two queries I get some records who are Active (may have such records whose `validTill < GETDATE()` but at least one record with `ValidTill > GETDATE()`) and still getting under Inactive records.

Need better query for Inactive records to avoid Active records coming along.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Dinav Ahire please provide sample data or expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get active records use query:

```
select * from table1
where table1Id in (
    select table1Id from Table2
    group by table1Id
    having max(ValidTill) >= getdate()
) a
```

In order to get inactive records use query:

```
select * from table1
where table1Id in (
    select table1Id from Table2
    group by table1Id
    having max(ValidTill) < getdate()
) a
```

Basically idea is that you group by `table1Id` and get maximum date (that latest) for that ID and then if that maximum ID is greater then current date - it's active, inactive otherwise.